# PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

Im learning php. Im confused in multi dimensional arrays. Im building a site which consists of latest gadget reviews and other stuff. Here my question how to make products menu (Mobiles, laptops, pc etc. )  by using key.

```
$products = array (
 "Mobiles" => array (
 "1" => array ( title="", desc="", price.      ="" ),
"2" => array ( title="", desc="", price ="" ),
),
"Laptops" => array (
"1" => array ( title="", desc="", price ="" ),
"2" => array ( title="", desc="", price ="" ),
),
);

 foreach($products as $key => $product)'
```

I need something like this :      products.php?search=mobiles
Here mobile is a key (thinks) 
search.php?id=1

I don't know much. I'm a newbie. Please help.  Thank you.

Edit :  i want to do this..
 http://mysongbook.ca/
Please go to the link.. There at the left side there is navigation menu (alphabets abcded).. Navigated to a list of artists songs.. That list directed to id title desc and so on page.. Here i need the same..

Index.php = list of products of a specific category = products content

Comment: sorry pal, can't really get the question. might want to try again?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you do have some syntax problems in that array of yours, i.e. `array ( title="", ...`.

Comment: @cylua2.. I updated the question.. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general example of the logic that you would want to set up...

```
<?php
 //var $products should be defined here

if($_GET['product']) {
  //Hit when url has a products variable 
  //Ex index.php?product=mobile
  var $product_breakdown = $products[$_GET['product'];
  //Do what ever you want to do with your products
} else {
  //Hit if you do not have a url variable for product
?>
  <!-- HTML OUTPUT THAT SENDS YOU BACK TO THE SAME PAGE -->
  <a href="index.php?Mobile">Mobile</a>
  <a href="index.php?Laptops">Laptops</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In php Arrays are similar to hashes. Instead of using "1", "2" you can use "Dell", "Mac". "1" and "2" are techincally keys.

So you could just do this:

```
$products = array (
  "Mobiles" => array (
     "iPhone6" => array ( 
         'title'=>"iPhone 6", 
         'desc'=>"Made by Mac", 
         'price'=>"699" 
     ),
     "iPhone5" => array ( 
        'title'=>"iPhone 5", 
        'desc'=>"Made by Mac", 
        'price'=>"599" 
     )
   ),
   "Laptops" => array (
     "Latitude" => array ( 
        'title'=>"Latitude", 
        'desc'=>"Made by Dell", 
        'price' =>"499" 
      ),
     "MacBookPro" => array ( 
       'title'=>"MacBook Pro", 
       'desc'=>"Made by Mac", 
       'price' =>"1299" 
      )
   )
);
```

Here is some more documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... it's been a little while since i've been in php. I've fixed the ones I noticed, lmk if there are more

Comment: You also need `'title' =>` instead of `title =>`, and so on.

Comment: True, but then in JS, you'd use an object, not an array ;)

Comment: Please take a look i updated the question. I know those minor things ("").

Comment: @seth those no. 's were id' s

Comment: @dan your original question has been answered. your edited question is based on how you set up your logic to handle $_POST variables, not how your array is set up.

Comment: @seth Oh cool.. Sry.. I use &_GET to handle variables. I was stuck. I don't know what to do. Im googling but nothing helps

Comment: @seth Ok. So can u help me out how to handle that.

Comment: You'll need to post what you have for your php code